# Yii framework redirect() didn't refresh my page (data loaded from cache)

Tags: caching, redirect, yii

My webpage have a form in Action A, which will submit to Action B (in the same controller).
Action will do checking and update the database, in some case the page will redirect back to Action A to let the user see the changes first, before go to another step.

I am using `this->redirect(array('item/?list_id='.$list_id'));` in controller.However after the redirect done, I only see the old data in the text input field, not the updated one in database(I have check the data in database has changed already), until I press F5 then I can see the correct updated data.

After checking the Chrome Developer Tools, I saw the php is load from cache. 
So now, What can I do to avoid browser load from cache after using redirect() ?

Comment: The call of the `redirect` method seems incorrect, it should be: `$this->redirect(array('item', 'list_id' => $list_id));`

Comment: can you share some codes?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid browser caching by adding parameter like :

```
$this->redirect(array(
    'item',
    'list_id' => $list_id,
    '_'       => time()
));
```